# Is there a Swifty way to unwrap optionals with string interpolation?

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm building a RESTful API query using values collected from the user. Some of those values might not be supplied, so I'm using optionals.  There are Double, Int and String values.  The code I'm using seems clunky.  Is there a cleaner, Swifty way to write this block of code?

'''Swift

```
let baseURL = "http......"

// Start with required parms
let format = "?format=\(parms.format)"
let endTime = "&endtime=\(parms.endDate)"

// now for optionals
let startTime = parms.startDate != nil ? "&starttime=\(parms.startDate!)" : ""

// Sorted by
let orderby = parms.orderby != nil ? "&orderby=\(parms.orderby!)" : ""
// parts.limit is Int?
let limit = parms.limit != nil ? "&limit=\(parms.limit!)" : ""

var strURL: String
strURL = "\(baseURL)\(format)\(startTime)\(endTime)\(orderby)\(limit)"
```

'''

I'm getting the result I need. E.g., if the user does not provide a StartDate parameter, it is not referenced in the query string.

'''
https://.....?format=geojson&endtime=2019-05-31&orderby=magnitude&minmagnitude=5&limit=2000
'''

but I have this feeling of missing the point of Swift Optionals

Comment: Not related to your need, but if that URL with param is your final goal, use `URLQueryItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 5 you can extend `String.StringInterpolation` and write custom interpolations. [Read More](https://ericasadun.com/2018/12/12/the-beauty-of-swift-5-string-interpolation/)

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    public mutating func appendInterpolation<T>(if value: T?, _ literal: StringLiteralType) {
        if let value = value {
            appendInterpolation(literal+"\(value)")
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of

```
let startTime = parms.startDate != nil ? "&starttime=\(parms.startDate!)" : ""
```

You can use

```
let startTime = "\(if: parms.startDate, "&starttime=")"
```

Usage

```
var startTime = "\(if: parms.startDate, "&starttime=")"
print(startTime)//""
parms.startDate = "mytime"
startTime = "\(if: parms.startDate, "&starttime=")"
print(startTime)//"""&starttime=mytime"
```

Comment: RajeshKumar, the problem is that if `parms.startDate` is nil, then your method will set `startTime` to `"&starttime="`. I first tried `let startTime = "&starttime=\(parms.startDate ?? "")"`.  Same effect as what you suggest.  But I need startTime to be empty.

Comment: I hadn't seen the update.  I like that you've used a new Swift construct.

Answer (score 5):

Don't build a URL by concatenating strings. Use `URLComponents`, and an array of `URLQueryItems`.

You can then either:

- not add items to the array of query items if the value is nil
- create them with nil `value` strings and filter when you're done.
- do something with `flatMap` for each optional parameter:

```
parms.startDate.flatMap { 
   parameters.append(URLQueryItem(name: "startttime", value: "\($0)"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for tipping me off to the existence of URLQueryItems.  Clearly intended for building queries as I am.